# TLA+ error : The invariant Invariants is not a state predicate

Tags: specifications, formal-methods, tla+, tlc

In my spec, I'm trying to check if a change in a sequence is either -1, 0 or 1.

I described this invariant as below :

```
PVariance == Len(waitingRoomP') - Len(waitingRoomP) \in {-1,0,1}
CVariance == Len(waitingRoomC') - Len(waitingRoomC) \in {-1,0,1}

Invariants ==
    /\ TypeInv
    /\ \/ PVariance 
       \/ CVariance
```

The TLC model checker outputs this :

```
The invariant Invariants is not a state predicate (one with no primes or temporal operators).
Note that a bug can cause TLC to incorrectly report this error.
If you believe your TLA+ or PlusCal specification to be correct,
please check if this bug described in LevelNode.java starting at line 590ff affects you.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`waitingRoomP'` is the value of `waitingRoomP` in the next state, meaning `PVariance` is now an action. Invariants can't be actions, they can only be "pure" operators.

You can instead check `PVariance` as an action property by writing `[][PVariance]_waitingRoomP`. This will need to be checked as a temporal property in the toolbox, not an invariant.